# Autosave buffer on :make in vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Is there any way to autosave the buffer before issuing :make?  I use MacVim and make is bound to Command-B, which is very helpful but I cannot seem to figure out how to write the buffer before a make.  I looked at all the autocmd events and nothing seemed to fit.

There's a QuickFixCmdPre which should be called before a make but can't seem to get it to work:

~/.vimrc

```
function! AutoSaveOnMake ()
    if &modified
        write
    endif
endfunction

autocmd QuickFixCmdPre *.c :call AutoSaveOnMake()
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vim has a built-in setting for that:

```
:set autowrite
```

> Write the contents of the file, if it has been modified, on each
>   :next, :rewind, :last, :first, :previous, :stop, :suspend, :tag, :!,
>   :make, CTRL-] and CTRL-^ command; and when a :buffer, CTRL-O, CTRL-I,
>   '{A-Z0-9}, or `{A-Z0-9} command takes one to another file.

Comment: I like that. Learn something new about vim everyday.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating an `autocmd` command, why not just update the Command-B mapping?

```
nnoremap <d-b> :update<bar>make<cr>
```

Comment: Can't seem to remap Command-B. If I try: nnoremap <F5> :update<bar>make<cr> for example, it works, but not <d-b>.

Comment: Make sure you put this in you `.gvimrc` file. See http://superuser.com/questions/249448/macvim-re-map-command-key-combinations-like-d-f

Comment: Got it working by combining the above remap command with the superuser comment.  As you said it has to go in `.gvimrc`